# Value of field which displays sum cannot be viewed on Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic field, where numeric values are entered and summed up to give total in the Grand total field.The code is as below :

[**Click here to view the code**](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyar/5fe4haq3/)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="questup.php">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="bs-example">
      <div class="Container">
        <table class="table table-hover small-text" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="tb" border="1px">
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <Footer Align="Center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
  </footer>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
      var students = 0;

      function studentTemplate(students) {

        return '<tr class="student_marks"><td>Marks</td><td> <input type="number" name="marks[]" class="marks student_' + students + ' form-control" student_ref="student_' + students + '" placeholder="Marks"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="addsubject" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th></tr><tr class="subtotal"> <td><b>Grand Total</b></td><td> <input type="text" name="subtotals[]" class="row-total student_' + students + ' form-control" disabled> </td></tr>';
      }

      function subTemplate(students) {
        return '<tr class="student_marks"><td>Marks</td> <td> <input type="number" name="marks[]" class="marks student_' + students + ' form-control" student_ref="student_' + students + '" placeholder="Marks"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="addsubject" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th> </tr>';
      }


      $('#tb tbody').append(studentTemplate(students));

      $('#tb tbody').on("click", "a.addsubject", function() {
        $(this).closest(".student_marks").after(subTemplate(students));
      });

      $('#tb tbody').on("keyup", "input.marks", function() {
        subtotal($(this).attr("student_ref"));
      });

      function subtotal(ref) {
        var sub = 0;
        $(".marks." + ref).each(function() {
          sub += $(this).val() != "" ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
        });
        $(".row-total." + ref).val(sub);
        calcTotal();
      }

    });
```

> **Issue**

When I submit my form, and call the grand total field using

```
$_POST['subtotals']
```

on the next page, it returns no value.

[image]

I tried debugging the data using `var_dump($_POST['subtotals'])` but it returns Null

> **PHP Code**

```
<?PHP
 echo var_dump($_POST['subtotals'])."<br/>";
 echo var_dump($_POST['marks'])."<br/>";

for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['marks']);$i++)
{

    echo "Marks : ".$_POST['marks'][$i]."<br/>";    
}

echo "Grand Total: ".$_POST['subtotals']."<br/>";

?>
```

How can I get the auto-summed field value onto the next page? I don't need a ready-made code, but would appreciate suggestions! :)

Comment: debug your data  using var_dump($_POST) to check whether the subtotals is coming in the request or not

Comment: on which page you are using the var_dump?

Comment: questup.php, the page it goes to on submit. Tried using it for marks too and it returns an array.

Comment: show the array that you got after submitting the form and also share the php code as well

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam added that in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your function with this one:

```
function studentTemplate(students) {

        return '<tr class="student_marks"><td>Marks</td><td> <input type="number" name="marks[]" class="marks student_' + students + ' form-control" student_ref="student_' + students + '" placeholder="Marks"> </td><th><a style="font-size:18px;width:33%;" class="addsubject" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th></tr><tr class="subtotal"> <td><b>Grand Total</b></td><td> <input type="text" name="subtotals[]" class="row-total student_' + students + ' form-control" > </td></tr>';
      }
```

I have removed the attribute "disable" for the field "subtotals". The input which are disabled can not be submitted.

Comment: Thank You! Wonder how I overlooked that :)

Comment: Adding to Faiyaz Answer, you can replace `disable` to `readonly` @SoumyaRao.